# Is it ok to recursively call a directive's link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/teydpa4t/3/)

This is a simplified version of a directive I have.  If I want to do something like this - essentially reinitialize the directive with a modified scope variable - is this ok?  Note that in the addSquare function, I call link() again.

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
var ddo = {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
        'numSquares': '@',
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
        console.log('link', scope.numSquares);

        scope.colors = [];


        attr.$observe('numSquares', function (newV, oldV) {
            for (var i = 0; i < scope.numSquares; i++) {
                var t1 = Math.random();
                var t2 = t1 * 0xFFFFFF << 0;
                var t3 = t2.toString(16);
                //var randomHex = (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
                console.log('push', t3);
                scope.colors.push('#' + t3);
            }
        });


        scope.addSquare = function () {
            scope.numSquares++;
            ddo.link(scope, elem, attr);
        }



    },
    template: '<div><input type="button" value="add square" ng-click="addSquare()"/><br><br><div ng-repeat="c in colors" class="square" style="background-color: {{c}}">aaa</div></div>'
};

return ddo;
```

});

By "ok", I mean:

- free of unintended side effects?
- considered good style?
- etc.

If not, what is the recommended alternative?

Comment: There is no recursion in your example. Furthermore there's absolutely no reason to call `link` again. Just add another color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ok. Indeed you will multiply the number of watchers (the `$observe` for instance) every time it is called and most likely face memory leaks.

What problem are you trying to solve exactly? Most likely, you need to add watchers (`scope.$watch`) if you want to refresh the directive elements based on scope changes, but there is no need to call the whole function again.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  My example just had a lot more initialization code to run when a new box was added.  It was easy to call the link function with just a couple lines of code, but with the extra watchers it's obviously not worth it.

Comment: Yeah, just add all of that logic in a `$scope.reset` function which you call initially and call again when the watcher fires for instance (that's typicall)